# Python: handling multiple installations of same version

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, python-requests

When I run a specific python program, I faced with an issue. While debugging I found out that the program is using libraries from different python installations.

For example, When I execute `pip freeze | grep requests` I get `requests==2.18.4`. But when the program runs, it somehow uses a `v2.2.1` `requests` library from `/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/api.py` location.

Then, when I executed `whereis python` I can see multiple directories in the output.

**Q1)** How can I solve this type of a problem **without using a virtualenv**? (i.e. conflicting library versions)

**Q2)** Or How can I upgrade the library at `/usr/share/*` directory?

**Q3)** How can I get rid of the multiple installations and stick with a single python installation?

Note: I am unable to use virtualenv because of an issue in the way the application is deployed.

Comment: I've run into this issue when I had the `requests` module installed via `pip` but **also** via `apt`. In my case the solution was to remove both of them and then re-install the `pip` version.

Comment: @rickdenhaan I just tried your suggestion, didn't work. :(

Comment: your `pip` may works with different `python` so it installs in different folder - try `python -m pip install ...` BTW you can get full path for every `python` and run with arg `-V` (to see its version - `/full/path/python -V` - you may have python in different version. I have installed 2.7, 3.5, 3.6 but I also had 2.6 and 2.3 (on Linux Mint) - and automatically I have command python2, python2.7, python3, python3.5, python3.6 and pip, pip2, pip2.7, pip3, pip3.5, pip3.6. In terminal write `python` and press `tab` two times and you may show you that you also have `python2`, etc.

Comment: Tangential but relevant: *use of [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) simplifies life immensely*, makes it explicit where you install what, and isolates projects from one another. I'd make a new virtualenv, install the required dependencies, and run the program from there. I'd suggest to _never_ develop something using the system Python installation, or `pip install` something into it. OS-provided Python should be only touched using the OS's package manager.

Comment: @9000 I agree. It's a very very very bad decision that the early developers of the program I am working had taken. But I am not able to change that now

Comment: "How can I solve this type of a problem without using a virtualenv" — can you please describe why virtualenv is not an option? What is the _root_ problem you're solving?

Comment: @9000 This program is installed in thousands of devices, and the script to start the program was shipped with the device itself. Thus to use a virtualenv, I have to change that script of all such devices individually, which is not feasible

Comment: @PubuduDodangoda: Oh! My condolences. On topic: how does the code import `requests`? Isn't there any code that searches for a particular version at import time? Also, have you checked `PYTHONPATH` values?

Comment: I import it like this, `from requests.api import request`. I am not explicitly setting a PYTHONPATH variable. So I guess it's the default value. But I will check and confirm

Comment: Won't help to solve your issue, but can still be helpful: run `$ python -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(p for p in sys.path))"` to see all the directories where Python imports the source code. From there, you may spot some non-obvious paths besides the default Python installation (should be smth like `/usr/lib/python2.7/{lib,lib-dynload,site-packages}`; observe the rest with caution!).